# SQL Query Does not work in c#

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server-2008

When I run the query below in SQL Management studio, it works brilliantly.

When i run it in c# the result has no rows (only the headers) - Why ?
I have single stepped through the code. Only the headers are returned. No Records.
Note: Query2 is defined as the SQL query.

**SQL Management Studio Query - Works**

```
SELECT 
    * 
FROM 
    [TraceData].[dbo].[MachineLog2] 
WHERE 
    [MachineFailReason] not like 'Passed' 
    AND Timestamp  >= CAST(GETDATE()-1 AS DATETIME) + CAST('04:00:00' AS DATETIME)  
ORDER BY Timestamp DESC
```

**C# Code - Does NOT Work**

```
SqlConnection conn2 = new SqlConnection(connectionString);  
string Query2 = @ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["Query2"];  
conn2.Open();

SqlCommand cmd2 = new SqlCommand(Query, conn2); 
SqlDataReader dr2 = cmd2.ExecuteReader();
```

Comment: Different databases?

Comment: When you say doesn't work - do you mean it returns no records? Have you walked through your code to ensure that AppSettings is correctly set and loaded?

Comment: How do you know it does not work? Have you called dr2.Read()?

Comment: btw `not like 'Passed'` should be `<> 'Passed'`

Comment: @Prescott yes i have walked through the code. No working means 0 records are returned given the same query that has results in SQL management studio.

Comment: @GordonLinoff i have updated the question to clarify

Comment: @Zee Yes i have singled stepped through the code. No results are returned given that the same query on management studio has results.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe a typo but you declare `Query2` and use `Query`

```
string **Query2** = @ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["Query2"];  
conn2.Open();

SqlCommand cmd2 = new SqlCommand(**Query**, conn2);
```

Comment: you are correct - that was the issue - i thought it was an issue embedding sql commands in c#

Answer (score 1):

Problems like this can be better debugged or completely solved by putting the Query in a stored procedure and just running the stored procedure using C#.

So your stored procedure creating query would looksomething like this

```
USE TraceData;
GO
CREATE PROCEDURE MyWrappedQuery

AS 
BEGIN

SELECT 
    * 
FROM 
    [TraceData].[dbo].[MachineLog2] 
WHERE 
    [MachineFailReason] not like 'Passed' 
    AND Timestamp  >= CAST(GETDATE()-1 AS DATETIME) + CAST('04:00:00' AS DATETIME)  
ORDER BY Timestamp DESC

END
```

And in C# you can either run the query 'exec MyWrappedQuery' or run the SP through ado.net

Try that and reply to this, It should work if the query works in SQL server but not through C#.

Comment: i dont have access on the server to create stored procedures.